# .net 6 Maui Blazor, null-coalescing operator ?? not working

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, maui

**Code**:

Ficha.razor

```
<h4 class="card-title">
  Básico @(PlayerViewState?.SelectedCharacter?.Description?.Name ?? "")
</h4>
```

PlayerViewState.cs

```
public class PlayerViewState
{
    public Player? Player { get; set; }
    public Character? SelectedCharacter { get; set; }
}
```

**Exception**:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> BlueMoonApp.ViewState.PlayerViewState.SelectedCharacter.get retornou null.

**Template:**

> .NET MAUI Blazor App (preview)

**Versions:**

> Framework: net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0

> Visual Studio: 17.2.0 Preview 6.0

**Problem:**

When I run this code, I get this expection, PlayerViewState has a object instance, but SelectedCharacter is null, so I tried to use `?` Prefix and `??` null-coalescing syntax.

It should have solved the **NullReferenceException**, shouldn't?

I set nullable enable in the csproj was well, blazor don't support the `?` Prefix and `??` null-coalescing syntax yet? why I'm getting this exception?

Comment: That looks like it should work. You are sure there is no code elsewhere that uses SelectedCharacter? If you remove that use (hard code to `Basico @("")`, the exception goes away? Is Character a class or struct?

Comment: The stacktrace should point you to a line. Probably not the one you think it is.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it is a class

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't think soo. 
if I do the same in the backend code it works, if a comment this piece of code it starts working again.

Comment: Sounds like you've done due-diligence, and encountered a bug. See if it works if you do the equivalent: `PlayerViewState?.SelectedCharacter != null && PlayerViewState.SelectedCharacter.Description != null ? PlayerViewState.SelectedCharacter.Description.Name : ""`